# Usage of numexpr contains() function

Tags: python, numpy, numexpr

I want to check if each element of a Numpy string array contains a given string using numexpr (2.7). I have written:

```
x = np.array(['abc', 'cde'])
ne.evaluate("contains(x, 'a')")
```

I get: `ValueError: unknown type str96`

I also tried to specify a `dtype` for `x` with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/issues/361). Try instead

```py
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne

x = np.array([b'abc', b'cde'])
ne.evaluate("contains(x, b'a')")
# array([ True, False])
```